# Excel Macro error

Tags: excel, vba

I get 2 errors on the script below:  Compile error and syntax error.

The error highlights the first row at sizes = Array(ext.

any help would be very nice and thank you

```
enter code here
Sub MakeFixedWidth()
Dim Sizes As Variant
Dim arr As Variant
Dim r As Long, c As Long
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TheLine As String
Dim TestStr As String


Sizes = Array(3, 3, 24, 24, 5, 1, 1, 8, 8, 2, 1, 1, 11, 11, 8, 1, 1, 5, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 4, 1, 29, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)






arr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Documents and Settings\dlund\Desktop\IHA3rdq.txt", True)

For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
TheLine = ""
For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
TestStr = Left(Trim(CStr(arr(r, c))), Sizes(c - 1))
TheLine = TheLine & TestStr & String(Sizes(c - 1) - Len(TestStr), " ")
Next c
ts.WriteLine TheLine
Next r

ts.Close

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have WAY too much text on a single line.  Try splitting it like this:

```
Sub MakeFixedWidth()
Dim Sizes As Variant
Dim arr As Variant
Dim r As Long, c As Long
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TheLine As String
Dim TestStr As String


Sizes = Array(3, 3, 24, 24, 5, 1, 1, 8, 8, 2, 1, 1, 11, 11, 8, 1, 1, 5, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, _
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, _
8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, _
1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, _
1, 8, 1, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, _
6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, _
6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 4, 1, 29, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, _
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)






arr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Documents and Settings\dlund\Desktop\IHA3rdq.txt", True)

For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
TheLine = ""
For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
TestStr = Left(Trim(CStr(arr(r, c))), Sizes(c - 1))
TheLine = TheLine & TestStr & String(Sizes(c - 1) - Len(TestStr), " ")
Next c
ts.WriteLine TheLine
Next r

ts.Close

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing that actual makes the macro run. Thank you. But I think the "_" makes the spacing off a litte in the file.   Does the "_" represent a continute?

Comment: the " _ " (without the quotes) is for the line break.  Notice the space before and after.  I'm not sure if you need the space(s) but it always seemed to work better for me when they're there, and I just started putting a space on either side out of habit.

Comment: You only need a space before the underscore

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks Tim...hopefully the old habit won't be a hard one to break.